# Превращение списка кортежей в список

Tags: haskell

Допустим, есть список кортежей вида

```
[("ключ 1", "значение 1"), ("ключ 2", "значение 2")]
```

Нужно получить список вида

```
["ключ 1 = значение 1", "ключ 2 = значение 2"]
```

Пораскинув мозгами, придумал такую функцию

```
fun d = result : fun $ tail d
  where
    result = [r]
    r = fst d' ++ snd d'
    d' = head d
```

Понимаю, что написал полную чушь, но это общий алгоритм, каким его я вижу.
Вопросы:
 - как будет выглядеть программа, которая преобразует нужным образом списки?
 - как правильно написать мой алгоритм?

Спасибо!

Answer (score 4):

В Вашем решении нет ничего плохого (кроме того, что оно, вроде, не скомпилируется, но типы и сообщения компилятора помогут сделать из этого компилируемый код), но большинство функций такого вида упрощаются с использованием `map`:

```
fun = map (\ r -> fst r ++ snd r)
```

А функции, подобные лямбде в скобках, упрощаются с использованием [`uncurry`](http://www.haskell.org/hoogle/?hoogle=uncurry):

```
fun = map (uncurry (++))
```

Изучайте стандартные функции, используйте [hoogle](http://www.haskell.org/hoogle/).

Хорошее упражнение по изучению [Prelude](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.7.0.1/docs/Prelude.html) (стандартная библиотека Haskell) — переписать её самому без подглядывания только по типам. Могу порекомендовать  домашние задания из [этого курса по функциональному программированию](http://oxij.org/activity/itmo/fp/2012/).

---

*P.S. На всякий случай: функции в следующем примере эквиваленты:*

```
f' xs = map g xs
f'' = map g
f''' = \ xs -> map g xs
```

Answer (score 2):

Ваша постановка задачи прямо-таки дословно транслируется в код с использованием паттерн-матчинга (сопоставления с образцом):

```
mapToList :: [(a,b)] -> [String]
mapToList []          = []
mapToList ((x,y):xys) = (show x ++ " = " ++ show y) : mapToList xys
```